Academic literature on effects of the digital divide on innovation
I work in research on both the digital divide and on the economics of innovation. Could someone please recommend some academic literature of the effects of the former on the latter?
To give you an idea of what I am looking for, important authors on these topics are Jan van Dijk, Christopher Freeman and Franco Malerba.
Thanks in advance!
